# How many XMM registers are available on an x86 processor supporting SSE?

Tags: x86, sse, cpu-registers, processor

How to find out the number of XMM registers on a processor which supports SSE?

On Intel X5550, for example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The number of XMM registers is fixed in all the processors that support SSE. If the CPU is in 32-bit mode, you can use 8 registers, from `xmm0` to `xmm7`, while if it's in 64-bit mode, you can address 16 registers, starting at `xmm0` up to `xmm15`. This is thanks to using the `REX.W` prefix.

Comment: Is that so? Current [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Streaming_SIMD_Extensions&oldid=564697556) says *and this extension is duplicated in the Intel 64 architecture.*

Comment: @ssice I don't understand your question entirely. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: The version I cited of the SSE article seems to say that in AMD64 (x86-64) you have up to `xmm15`, and that number is *double* in the Intel 64, so Intel 64 has up to `xmm31`? How could we check whether xmm31 will be available or not? (Or have I understood it incorrectly?)

Comment: You must've misunderstood the context. _Duplicated_ would have to refer to the new instructions being available on the Intel 64 architecture as well. I haven't seen any mention of 32 `xmm` registers anywhere in the Intel documentation.

Comment: Read wiki again it clearly said for Intel64 you have xmm0 to xmm7 AND for amd64 you have 0 to 15